# Gettng undefined offset:0

Tags: php

I get this Undefined offset: 0

```
$lasttrade = BaseDonnee::execQuery($bdd, "SELECT Price FROM Trade_History WHERE 
Market='$ipair' ORDER BY Timestamp DESC LIMIT 1")[0]["Price"];
```

What is this problem? and how do I solve this? the BaseDonne::execQuery function is this

```
static function execQuery($bdd, $query){
try{
    $req = $bdd->prepare($query);
    $req->execute();
    $result = $req->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
    $req->closeCursor();
    return $result;
} catch( PDOEXception $e ) {
       echo $e->getMessage(); // display bdd error
       exit();
   }


}
```

Comment: That means you aren't getting any results

Comment: Yes, but why no results.

Comment: You tell *us*. We don't know your system or data. Have you bothered to run this query against your DB? Do you get results? Are you sure this query is right? Does the variable in your query which leaves you open to SQL injection have a value? Is it what you expected? This is all basic troubleshooting.

Comment: This isn't my system. I downloaded it via github, to run and understand bitcoin trading. It's only been an hour and have been trying to get rid of a few bugs :)